# How can I make list items fill up a div horizontally?

Tags: css, html, html-lists, zooming, listitem

I have a div and, inside it, an unordered list with several list items that serve as navigation menu items. The list items, when hovered over, turn a certain background color different from other items in the list. I wonder how I can make sure that the list items always completely fill the div horizontally, no matter what the zoom level. Currently, when I view the page at 100% zoom, the list items fill the navigation div completely (there is no empty space between the last list item and the right border of the div), but when I zoom out, an empty area appears to the right of the last list item.

Ideally, I would like to do this using CSS. What property or properties in the CSS should I adjust to make sure that the div and the space taken up by the list items always shrink or expand at the same rate when I zoom in or out?

I myself can't see the HTML code (I'm modifying a template), which also means that I can't set the width for each list item individually, but the CSS for the unordered list looks as follows:

```
#navigation ul {
width: 100%;
resize: vertical;
}

#navigation li {
float: left;
position: relative;
resize: vertical;
}
```

The resize:vertical and float:left were added by me as part of my efforts to make the unordered list always span the width of the div. As you can see, the unordered list's width is already set to 100%, and yet it does not fill the div except when the page is viewed at 100% zoom. If nothing else works, is there a way to make the div or the font of the menu items not be resized when the user zooms in or out on the page?

Comment: Use float left... however if don't provide your code, can't answer properly

Comment: if i understand your question corectly, try using ems instead of pixels for font size and ems for divs

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Impressum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please upload your code.

However if my understanding is correct set the width of the unordered list to 100% this way if should span the full length of the div.

```
ul{ width:100%; }
```

That should do it.

Comment: I tried this. However, when I zoom out of the page, the font size of the list items shrinks and they no longer fill up the div again.

Comment: Set there font-size using em as opposed to px eg. ul li{font-size:2em;}

Answer (score 0):

I would use a percentage width for the list elements `li`.  Here is my overly simplistic jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XT3gU/

Set the width of the `ul` to 100%.  Divide 100 by number of list items.  I used 4, so 100/4 = 25.

You'll need to keep an eye on sub-pixel rounding issues if your percentage value equates to something like 161.75px each.

*HTML*

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```css
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but the problem is that my list items vary quite a bit in length (some contain two words), so that giving each the same percentage of the div's width makes the shorter ones look lonely while the longer ones sprawl over two lines in some cases. I'm trying now to think of what else can be done.

Comment: You could target each `li` individually.  You will most likely have to set each one to a specified width that in the end will total 100%.  Something like 15% + 35% + 20% + 30% = 100%.  Using percentages will get you the zoom feature you are looking for.  Pixel widths won't zoom.

Comment: I'll try this, and also using ems for divs.

Comment: Not sure I would use ems for your DIVs as they are based on font size. Fonts don't always render exactly the same size in each browser.

Comment: A lot of the HTML code is hidden from me, so there is only so much I can do to edit it. I've tried to set the width of the unordered list to 100%, but that doesn't seem to work when I zoom out of the page, because the characters in the list items still get smaller. Is there a way to stop the font of the list items from resizing, so that the font appears the same at all zoom levels? Would the no-resizing be a property of the list items, the list, or the containing div?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers!

I finally figured out how to do this. My situation was complicated by the fact that I was modifying a template and so much of the HTML was hidden from me. I could edit CSS all I wanted, however, and I figured out that I could individually adjust the width of each list item using CSS as follows:

```
#navigation .w-menu-item.wsite-nav-3 {
width: 5%;
}
```

, where the 3 in wsite-nav-3 is the number of the list item. This, and getting rid of the float-left in the unordered-list properties in the CSS, but keeping it in the list-item properties, achieved the desired effect--the unordered list items now fill up their entire div no matter what the zoom level.